# PyInstaller: "ImportError: No module named os"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to learn PyInstaller. I created two simple files, Test.py:

```
import os
```

and Test.spec:

```
anal = Analysis (["Test.py"])
pyz = PYZ(anal.pure)
exe = EXE(anal.scripts, pyz, name="Test.exe", exclude_binaries=1, debug=1)
coll = COLLECT(exe, anal.binaries, name="dist")
```

Then I ran:

```
Build.py Test.spec
```

This ran without any error mesages, and produced a directory dist with several files, including Test.exe. When I ran Test.exe, it failed with the output:

```
Found embedded PKG: C:\Documents and Settings\Rade\My Documents\Development\Test\Test.exe
Extracting binaries
manifestpath: C:\Documents and Settings\Rade\My Documents\Development\Test\Test.
exe.manifest
Error activating the context
python27.dll
Manipulating evironment
PYTHONPATH=C:/Documents and Settings/Rade/My Documents/Development/Test
importing modules from CArchive
extracted iu
extracted struct
extracted archive
Installing import hooks
outPYZ1.pyz
Running scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
RC: -1 from Test
OK.
```

I'm sure I have made some stupid beginner's mistake, but what?

Comment: Im running into the same issue, and I did generate the spec file via Makespec.py :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple files like this, you should use `Makespec.py` for creating spec's instead of writing manually. For large projects, you could use the Makespec.py's output as a template and edit them.

http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/tags/1.4/doc/Manual.html#create-a-spec-file-for-your-project